# Make character only can jump when touching the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a character jump only when he is with his feet on the ground. I don't want him to be able to 'air-jump', so I came with this solution:

```
if (JumpButtonPressed()) {
    if (GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))) {
        velocity.y = jumpForce;
    }
}
```

The idea is that only when in touch with a "Ground" Layer, it can jump. But this is what happens:

[image]

It doesnt work just on his foot. If he is touching a platform by the side, it can jump as well. What could I do?

Comment: You probably need more than a single collider. Imagine one box around the whole character, and another collider (for the jump) just below the feet - not as wide as the full body. So the side of the body would collide with the wall, stopping you moving walking into it. And the "jump" collider won't meet the wall because it is less wide than the body collider. But if you collide from above, the jump collider will be the one to collide, not the body.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use a raycast downwards below the character to determine whether he is grounded. If a single raycast is too narrow, try `Physics2D.BoxCast()` instead, and make its width just as wide as the character's collider so it won't hit any colliders next to the character.

Comment: Yeah, that is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [circle overlap](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) with a position vector which is placed at the bottom on the player. Detect layer from there.

You may need to use different layer for platform if you want to write features like ledge grab, jump.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool isJumping and set it to true while in the air. When it reaches the ground - set it to false. Smth like that if your snippet is in Update():

```
bool isJumping = false;
if (JumpButtonPressed() && !isJumping) {
if (GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))) {
    velocity.y = jumpForce;
    isJumping = true;
}
}
if (GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"))) {
    isJumping = false;
}
```